# Changes in Hosts file lost when not using -writable-system in Android Emulator

Tags: android-emulator

I updated the /system/etc/hosts file in Android emulator by starting the emulator with the flag -writable-system.

```
emulator.exe -avd tablet -writable-system
```

When I restarted the emulator without the -writable-system flag, my changes to the hosts file were gone.
If I restart the emulator with the -writable-system flag on, I can see my changes there and everything works as expected (without updating the file again nor remounting).

Why is this happening? Is it possible to start the Android emulator without that flag and preserve my changes to the hosts file?